# Select 2 columns from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables:

```
Table t1:     Table t2:     Table t3:     
+----+----+   +----+----+   +----+----+   
| i1 | i2 |   | i2 | c2 |   | i1 | c1 |   
+----+----+   +----+----+   +----+----+   
|  1 | 22 |   |  11| cc |   |  1 | e  |   
|  2 | 33 |   |  22| bb |   |  2 | f  |   
|  3 | 11 |   |  33| aa |   |  3 | g  |   
+----+----+   +----+----+   +----+----+
```

and I want to select the colum c2 from t2 and c1 from t3 using the table t1 with the columns i1 and i2 and the result would be thins:

```
requested Tabel:     
+----+----+   
| c1 | c2 |   
+----+----+   
|  e | bb |   
|  f | aa |   
|  g | cc |   
+----+----+
```

I did a select with a union like this:

```
select pve.c1
from dbo.t3 as pve
join dbo.t1 as v
on pve.i1 = v.i1
union
select vse.c2
from dbo.t2 as vse
join dbo.t1 as e
on vse.i2 = e.i2
```

and the result is this:

```
resulted Tabel:     
+----+
| i1 |
+----+
|  e |
|  f |
|  g |
|  bb|
|  aa|
|  cc|
+----+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT  c.c1, b.c2
FROM    t1 a
            INNER JOIN t2 b
                on a.i2 = b.i2
            INNER JOIN t3 c
                on a.i1 = c.i1
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d314c/3)

Comment: @XandrUu Yuo're welcome! Don't forget to accepts answers to avoid from lowering reputation. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.i2=t2.i2
JOIN t3 ON t1.i1=t3.i1;
```